# How to Insert Update Trigger sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have 2 tables `dbo.booking` and `dbo.seat` with these structures:

- `dbo.booking` has columns `noBooking, noSeat, start, [end], statusBooked`
- `dbo.seat` has columns `noSeat, statusSeat`

Every row of data I insert to `dbo.booking` (`statusBooked` value set to 1) then on `dbo.seat` column `statusSeat` (is 0 by default) will updated to 1.

If `statusBooked` is updated to 0 then `statusSeat` will also update to 0.

I mean `statusSeat` (0 by default) will update and follow `statusBooked` value.

I tried using a trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerUpdateSeat] 
ON [dbo].[booking]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
    UPDATE dbo.seat
    SET seat.statusSeat = i.statusBooked
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE dbo.seat.noSeat = i.noSeat;
```

But the problem is when the first time I insert data on `dbo.booking`, `dbo.seat` filled `statusSeat` is must update to 1 but it's not updated to 1 it doesn't work. But for the second and forward it works. `statusSeat` value is following `statusBooked` value.

The problem happens only the first time I run my program and do insert data.

Why?

Comment: It seems your table `seat` references `booking` via the `noSeat` column - right? So why do you even need that `statusSeat` column? Just do a join to the `dbo.Booking` table and read out `statusBooked` - no point in having two columns that contains the same information, and worrying about keeping them in sync - avoid this data redundancy!

Comment: yes, seat references booking via noSeat column.
because I have some seat and I want to show which booked and which available, so I add statusSeat. statusBooked is for the 'transaction' status only. if I didn't add statusSeat it will be hard for me to execution in another case on my project. so how to solve my problem above ? @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you wanted to see the data in Booking and the matching data in Seat. You would do that with a join.

```
select  b.*, s.*
from    Booking  b
join    Seat     s
   on   s.noSeat = b.noSeat;
```

But you want to limit the result set to where the seat status values are different.

```
select  s.*, b.*
from    Seat     s
join    Booking  b
   on   b.noSeat = s.noSeat
   and  b.statusBooked <> s.statusSeat;
```

Now just turn that into an `update` statement. But also, this is inside the trigger, so it's not actually Booking you use.

```
update  s
    set s.statusSeat = b.statusBooked
from    Seat     s
join    Inserted b
   on   b.noSeat = s.noSeat
   and  b.statusBooked <> s.statusSeat;
```

Comment: i don't get it. please explain me more

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Try this. Choose a few rows in Seat and change the value of statusSeat so it doesn't match the status in Booking. Then execute each of the queries I posted above. Seeing the data all laid out for you like that can be quite enlightening. Then execute the update statement -- except use Booking instead of Inserted. Does it work? If at any time there is something specific you don't understand, show us the results you got and tell us what about it you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If am right, this will solves your problem. Your `statusSeat` column will be updated as in `statusBooked` column  if `statusBooked` Updated. And Your `statusSeat` column will be updated as in `statusBooked` column  if `statusBooked` Inserted and `statusBooked` is greater than 0(Because it's defaultly 0).

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerUpdateSeat] 
    ON [dbo].[booking]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
    AS
IF UPDATE (statusBooked)
BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.seat
            SET seat.statusSeat = i.statusBooked
            FROM Inserted i
            WHERE dbo.seat.noSeat = i.noSeat;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.seat
            SET seat.statusSeat = i.statusBooked
            FROM Inserted i
            WHERE dbo.seat.noSeat = i.noSeat and i.statusBooked>0;
END
```